# C# Prevent Call Hang with Child Thread CallBack

Tags: c#, multithreading, freeze

I have the following code that in a very specific scenario, will hang indefinitely:

```
connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Unfortunately, the hang is outside my control in this very specific scenario.

So I would like to be able to handle this scenario and at the very least throw an exception.

I would like to spin of a child thread that will callback the main thread when it timeouts.

How would you do that - here is my attempt:

```
OdbcConnection connection = null;

var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
bool exceptionThrown = false;

var connectionThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        resetEvent.Set();
    }
});

connectionThread.Start();

var isOk = resetEvent.WaitOne(timeout);

if(exceptionThrown)
{
   throw now Exception("Exception connection to DB");
}

if (!isOk)
{
    connectionThread.Abort();
    const string messageFormat = "Timeout of {0} reached while creating OdbcConnection to {1}.";
    throw now Exception(string.Format(messageFormat, timeout, connectionString));
}
```

UPDATE:
Here is my attempt using Task:

```
OdbcConnection connection = null;
var connectionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
});
try
{
    connectionTask.Wait(1000);       // Wait for 1 second.
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in connection");
}

bool completed = connectionTask.IsCompleted;
if(!completed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Timed-out");
}
else
{
    connection.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Not really.  You're going to start a thread that sleeps for 3 seconds.  Then you're going to wait for that thread for only 2 seconds.  The (exceptionThrown) will never be true (also mark it as volatile).  Also, although you can call Thread.Abort that's not good practice either.  What version of .NET are you working with?  If you can use a Task it would be much simpler.  If not, let me know what you want and I may be able to help, if someone else doesn't first.  I've got a decent understanding of threads.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I've updated now.  The Sleeps were just for testing purposes.  I am .NET 4.5

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.5 then I would highly recommend Task and using async / await.  However; just using a task alone would save you a headache here.  As far as the thread goes; I recommend working the entire communication to the OdbcConnection on the new thread (hopefully Task :D )  Just pass the work needed to the new thread and run it all from there.  Another thing; if you start a background thread just to immediately wait on it then it's pointless; however, I do realize you're trying to implement a timeout period.  A well written Task and async await would save you from blocking.

Comment: What's the desired result again?

Comment: So your code does not achieve the desired result?

Comment: It functions - but I am not sure it is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

Why not setting the Timeout property?

```
OdbcConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 15
```

The docs on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) state:

> Unlike the .NET Framework data providers for SQL Server and OLE DB, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support setting this property as a connection string value, because it is not a valid ODBC connection keyword. To specify a connection time-out, set the ConnectionTimeout property before calling Open.

**Update**

I think the bug in Mometdb is that there are reading `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` ([See source on GitHub](https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/blob/b40c1c1a33feece365fa6655802b6577df04af62/clients/odbc/driver/SQLSetConnectAttr.c#L77)), while it should be `SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMOUT`, [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> To specify a connection time-out, set the ConnectionTimeout property before calling Open. This is equivalent to setting the ODBC SQLSetConnectAttr SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMOUT attribute.

I think passing `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=15` to the connectionstring should work.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with the ODBC Driver for MonetDB

Answer (score 2):

I am  not sure what you exact requirement is. But if you are just trying to establish a ODBC connection async and you would like to do error handling then I think the below should work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connstring = "connstring");
        try
        {
            Program.Method(connstring);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var m = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    static async Task<int> Method(string connstring)
    {
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connstring);

            await conn.OpenAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var m = ex.Message;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

- Make the caller function async;
- Declare a new Task where you do stuff with the connection;
- Handle exception in the caller.

  ```
  static async void Main(string[] args)
  {
      try
      {
          await DoSomething("");
      }
      catch (TimeoutException ex)
      {
          // Handle Exception.
      }
      catch (SomeOtherException ex)
      {
          // Handle Exception.
      }
  }

  static Task DoSomething(string connectionString)
  {
      OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
      connection.Open();
      connection.DoSomethingElse();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There are a fundamental difference between await/async and Task.Wait:

> [await (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/hh156528.aspx) - An await expression **does not block the thread on which it is executing**. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off.
>
> [Task.Wait, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) - Wait is a synchronization method that causes the calling thread to wait until the current task has completed. If the current task has not started execution, the Wait method attempts to remove the task from the scheduler and execute it inline on the current thread. If it is unable to do that, or if the current task has already started execution, **it blocks the calling thread until the task completes**.

From what I have understood, you have a UI application which, at a certain point, attempts to open an OdbcConnection. This operation requires some time during which the UI is blocked.
If I am correct, this is a very small example which doesn't block the UI:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool completed = await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingLong());

        if (!completed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not completed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        }
    }

    bool DoSomethingLong()
    {
        //This loop will take 15 seconds
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("<DoSomethingLong> - I am alive");

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead for Task:

```
            OdbcConnection connection = null;
        var connectionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        });

        connectionTask.ContinueWith((tsk) => 
        {
            if(tsk.Exception==null && tsk.IsCompleted)
            {
                connection.DoSomething();
            }
            else
            {
                // here you can examine exception that thrown on task
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Timed-out");
            }
        });
```